# Using multiple variables to index a single axis (row or column) of an array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-indexing

I am fairly new to python and I am working with square matrices of which have size 'n' equal to a power of 2 (4x4, 8x8, etc).
Instead of indexing the rows (and columns) from 0 to n-1, I want to index them using ordered pairs of two variables, so that I can extract on "sub-matrices" from the whole matrix.

For example, say I have the 4x4 matrix

```
M = [[1   2   3   4  ]
     [5   6   7   8  ]
     [9   10  11  12 ]
     [13  14  15  16]]
```

Then I want to index the rows using the binary variables `(r1,r2)` so that in this case the rows should be numbered as `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1)`. The columns will be indexed similarly by `(c1,c2)`.  This allows me to divide the matrix into four 2x2 "sub-matrices" based on the values of of `r1` and `c1`.

So IDEALLY, I am expecting to get an indexing like this:

```
print(M[(0,0),(0,0)])
>>> 1

print(M[(1,0),(1,1)])
>>> 12

print(M[(0,1),])
>>> [5  6  7  8]

print(M[(0,),(0,)])
>>> [[1  2]
     [5  6]]
```

Note that the variables will always not be binary valued. For eg. in an 8x8 matrix, for the pair `(r1,r2)`, I have `r1=[0,1]` and `r2=[0,1,2,3]`. The pairing will now divide the complete matrix into four 4x4 sub-matrices.

I could do this by introducing new variables and mapping them to each value of the default indexing, but is there a more efficient way of achieving this? I feel like there has to be a built-in function in `numpy` or something that can do this task.

Comment: will `.reshape()` do what you're after?

Comment: please be explicit, what are the exact expected outputs for your examples?

Comment: Read the main numpy indexing page.  To get block you need a pair of arrays that broadcast together.  eg `x[ np.ix([1,2], [3,4]) ]`

Comment: @mozway I edited the question to include the expected behavior

Comment: @hpaulj `numpy.ix_` could work! Thanks. Though I would have to define each block individually, right?. That could be difficult for larger matrix sizes. And in a separate case, for 8x8 matrices I also need an indexing with three binary variables for each row, and I'm not sure how that could be efficiently done using this method.

Comment: This may not be so efficient, but your indexes will always be `r1 * n//2 +r2`. The same logic can be easily extended to more than two variables